# Why だからよ is considered "girly talk" and だからね is not?

Tags: slang, spoken-language, particle-ね, particle-よ

So I was talking to a friend when he told me, as the title says, that:

> **だからよ** is "girly talk" but **だからね** is correct

for instance:

> 昨日は楽しい、お酒を飲んだからね (according to him, totally ok and natural)
>
> 昨日は楽しい、お酒を飲んだからよ (according to him, girly talk) it should in fact be:
>
> 昨日は楽しい、お酒を飲んだから**だ**よ

It's weird for me because, in everything else I studied so far, both this particles seem to respect the same grammar rules (though I know this is not really a grammar point but a "pattern" in the spoke language)

Is it correct? Is this the only case where these partciles behave differently

Comment: Generally, omitting だ is considered feminine in these kinds of situations, so that's why.

Comment: I undestand that, but why is だからね not feminine then?

Comment: It's a question of tone and context. Using ね while explaining something is pretty neutral. But using ね and よ when requesting something or in otherwise casual speech is considered feminine. Same can be said of よね, unless preceded by だ or です. Actually concluding the sentence with だ or です is affirmative and is considered masculine.

In short, the gist is that male speech is centered on facts, and female speech is centered on emotions. At least, that's my understanding. I might be wrong...!

Comment: If you could make this into an answe, we could see what other people think about it ^-^

Comment: I would, but I'm not 100% confident that it is an answer...

Comment: I don't know about the first half, but I totally agree with the second half of psosuna's comment. Not to say the difference between male and female thought processes is truely as such, but the idea is definitely what's behind these different ways of speaking

Comment: @holyeyeolo no arguing on that, but what's weird for me, is that if that's really the case, this phenomenon would happen is other situations too, still sentences like 静かね are considered wrong, both 静かだね、静かだよ seem to be the right approach. So it seems that that's the only case where that happens (?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's a combination of the reasoning we stated above *and* the way it sounds. My last unanswered question was exactly that. Only a native speaker could say exactly which cases are girly and which are masculine... You have to study culture for this matter, not language

Comment: @holyeyeolo what I mean is, that I already knew that からよ was feminine, any noun/na adjective + よ is considered feminine talking, but also as I knew any noun/na-adjective +　ね is at least ungrammatical, so my guess was "since からだよ is the correct, grammatical and 'masculine' way of saying, therefore からだね is also the right way" but then I was corrected to "からだよ and からね" is what is actually right. I don't know if that makes it any clearer, but besides feminine or not, is a matter of grammar changing in a weird way (in my opnion) in this case

Comment: It all looks like fine grammar to me. The only example which might be wrong is 静かね which I think needs だ. よ and ね have nothing to do with grammar. They have nothing to do with feminine/masculine either *unless* you take culture and the way it all sounds together in each private case into account. Hope this helps

Comment: psosuna wrote: "In short, the gist is that male speech is centered on facts, and female speech is centered on emotions." ← I really hope we can get away from naive ideas like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

…からよ can be interpreted as two usages.

One is a sentence ender with だ omitted, in other words, it's interchangeable to …からだよ, albeit it's slang among women in a certain generation or 役割語 for female characters. （静かね is parallel to this.)

The other one is filler usage, this time, it's not interchangeable to …からだよ but just added to the sub clause …から, which is slang too, and also a 役割語 for the delinquent.

And the point is, the filler usage with ね is accepted in Standard Japanese. That's why he said it's correct.

Difference between main clause and sub clause

- main clause: それは酒を飲んだからだ (It is because I drank alcohol)
- sub clause: 楽しかった。酒を飲んだから。(I was happy because I drank alcohol)

In the former sentence, 飲んだからだ is the predicate of the sentence or the main clause. And particles like な, ね or よ that follow it are a sentence ending particle, in other words, ones as in それは酒を飲んだからだよ or それは酒を飲んだからよ.

In the latter, 飲んだから is a sub clause, and particles that appear after it are a filler.

Comment: hmmm in a more standard japanese I could assume that からね is ok for both genders and so just から as well right?  but ending with よ is not natural for standard japanese at all? Should I maybe refrain from using からだよ to end a sentence?

Comment: So called feminine language is supposed to be slang (or dialectal?) but somehow overlooked. Unlike that, からだよ is just standard. You still seem to mix two different things. Again, one is a main clause or a sentence while the other is just a sub clause.

Comment: do you mean that when I lack the だ I am doing a subclause? Sorry, this is very cloudy for me still